# Why the following could determine if str1 and str2 are anagram?

Tags: java

I am reading a code snippet and I am wondering why the following could 
check if str1 and str2 are anagram.

```
boolean result =  str1.chars().allMatch( c1 -> str2.chars()
                   .anyMatch( c2 -> c1 == c2) );
```

I am particularly confused about 
if str1 = "abc"  str2 = "cbad", the result should be also true, right?

Comment: (EDIT) No. `str1` does not have the character `d`

Comment: is not that lamdba actually match every single character in `str1` to `str2`?

Comment: you mean str1 does not have "d"?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes. Corrected it

Comment: It doesn't. The claim this checks anagrams is incorrect.

Comment: I think it is true because you'll check if any character in `str1` is in `str2` which is correct.

Comment: ah, apparently your question *str1 = "abc" str2 = "cbad", the result should be also true* should be also true, sorry i did not read the question properly. that code wont work well if `str2` had additional character not in str1.

Answer (score 5):

> I am particularly confused about if str1 = "abc" str2 = "cbad", the result should be also true, right?

The code will return `true`, yes. So no, it's not a valid check for an anagram, since in the example you cite, it will say it's an anagram when it's not (since `str1` doesn't have `d`).

In an anagram, both strings would need to have the same number of occurrences of the same letters. One byproduct of that is that they would need to be the same length (although in some anagram schemes, you're allowed to vary the number of spaces and add/remove punctuation).

So a valid check would need to ensure that every character in `str1` (perhaps ignoring spaces and punctuation) *consumed* a character from `str2`, and that there were no characters from `str2` left at the end (perhaps ignoring spaces and punctuation). There are lots of ways to do that (count the occurrences in `str1`, perhaps in a `Map`, and then count down matches from `str2`; have a string you remove letters from, etc.) The quoted code just isn't one of them.

Comment: But also, it will return true for "aabc" and "abc".

Comment: @AndyTurner - Good point. It's really just not a good check at all.

Comment: so the better to trim all spaces, then check for whether the inverse is true (`str1` and `str2` switches place) and check for the string's length?

Comment: @BagusTesa - There are lots of ways to do it. The quoted code just isn't one of them (not even if you run it again reversing `str2` and `str1`, see Andy's point above).

Comment: Bagus Tesa, no, absolutely not, if you do it that way, then aad and add match

Answer (score 1):

If you have str1 = "abc" and str2 = "cbad", they cannot be anagram of each other because str2 contains the extra character d which str1 does not have. For one word to be an anagram of the other word, they each needs to have the same character with the same number of frequencies.

That being said, I just ran the code you have written and it does not work for that specific case that you have mentioned.

One way you can determine if one string is an anagram of another string is by using two HashMap. For each strings, loop through it, track each character as the key and its frequencies as value. At the end, you can loop through both of the HashMap and keep comparing the value for each key. If the values are not equal, return false.

Also first thing to check is that the length of both strings should be equal. If they fail that condition, they cannot be an anagram then.

The following is the code I wrote on LeetCode many months ago. This can definitely be optimized and made much more cleaner but just to give you an idea.

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean isAnagram(String s, String t) {
        if (s.length() != t.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        HashMap<Character, Integer> tmap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (map.containsKey(c)) {
                int count = map.get(c);
                map.put(c, count + 1);
            }
            else {
                map.put(c, 1);
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < t.length(); j++) {
            char d = t.charAt(j);
            if (!(map.containsKey(d))) {
                return false;
            }
            if (tmap.containsKey(d)) {
                int tracker = tmap.get(d);
                tmap.put(d, tracker + 1);
            }
            else {
                tmap.put(d, 1);
            }
        }
        for (Character key: map.keySet()) {
            int mapv = map.get(key);
            int tmapv = tmap.get(key);
            if (mapv != tmapv) {
                System.out.println(tmapv);
                System.out.println(mapv);
                return false;
            }
        } 
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first for loop could be written more concisely as `map.merge(s.charAt(i), 1, (a, b) -> a + b))`. The second for loop could be written in terms of decrementing the counts in `map`, and breaking once the count is negative (which handles the case of "too many" of the letter in the second string). And then just look for a key with non-zero count at the end.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes you are right. I already mentioned in my response that I wrote the following code a long time ago on Leetcode when I didn't have much programming experience and I just copied and pasted it on here. 

Thank you for sharing your idea though. I didn't know about this approach and I am excited to try it approach now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51465641/8089107) this should be a possible way to check for an anagram:

```
public static boolean isAnagram(String subject, String possibleAnagram, IntPredicate isAnagramCodePoint)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(subject);
    Objects.requireNonNull(possibleAnagram);
    Objects.requireNonNull(isAnagramCodePoint);

    // Convert inputs to valid anagram letters.
    int[] subjectLetters = subject.codePoints()
            .filter(isAnagramCodePoint)
            .toArray();

    int[] possibleAnagramLetters = possibleAnagram.codePoints()
            .filter(isAnagramCodePoint)
            .toArray();

    // Permutation = Same number of occurrences of the same letter.

    if (subjectLetters.length != possibleAnagramLetters.length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<>(subjectLetters.length);

    // Count (produce) number of occurrences for each letter in subject.
    for (int codePoint : subjectLetters)
    {
        occurrences.merge(codePoint, 1, (a, b) -> a + b);
    }

    // Consume each letter occurrence from subjectLetters.
    for (int codePoint : possibleAnagramLetters)
    {
        int val = occurrences.merge(codePoint, -1, (a, b) -> a + b);

        if (val == -1)
        {
            return false; // Current letter occurred more often in possibleAnagram
        }
    }

    // Check equal number of occurrences for the same letter.
    for (int number : occurrences.values())
    {
        if (number != 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private static final IntPredicate COMPLETE = (codePoint) -> true;

public static boolean isAnagram(String subject, String possibleAnagram)
{
    return isAnagram(subject, possibleAnagram, COMPLETE);
}
```

The optional `IntPredicate` is used to specify the anagram schema, a possible value could be `Character::isLetter` to ignore all code points except letters, `Character::isDigit`, etc.